# GridSearch for XGBoost

Tags: xgboost, grid-search, gridsearchcv

I am reading the grid search for XGBoost on [Analytics Vidhaya](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2016/03/complete-guide-parameter-tuning-xgboost-with-codes-python/).
It has the following in the code

```
param_test1 = {'max_depth':range(3,10,2), 'min_child_weight':range(1,6,2)}
gsearch1 = GridSearchCV(estimator = XGBClassifier( learning_rate =0.1, 
                                                   n_estimators=140, 
                                                   max_depth=5,
                                                   min_child_weight=1, 
                                                   gamma=0, 
                                                   subsample=0.8, 
                                                   colsample_bytree=0.8,
                                                   objective= 'binary:logistic', 
                                                   nthread=4, 
                                                   scale_pos_weight=1, 
                                                   seed=27), 
                        param_grid = param_test1,
                        scoring='roc_auc',
                        n_jobs=4, iid=False, 
                        cv=5)
```

My quesiton is if the grid search is used to find a better `max_depth` and `min_child_weight`,
then why these two parameters are set in `gsearch1` as 5 and 1, respectively.

Moreover, in my own code when I comment these two out, then the result changes. Why is that?

Thanks

Comment: The result will never be the same. If you uncomment and run the code again, then you will not get the previous result due to random weight initialization. Grid search just brute force the parameters from param grid and provide the best values based on scoring.

Comment: Sure. Thanks, I can set the seed and double check. How about the first question, why it even is there? just because it does not make any difference?

Comment: Even if you don't set the max_depth and min_child_weight it would not make any difference as far as i know because they are going to be replaced by values in param grid. But the final result of grid search i.e the best values of both parameters will not change